# fatal: bad ownership or modes for chroot directory component "/"

Tags: linux, ubuntu, permissions, sftp

I created an sftp only user called sftp with the following rules:

```
Match User xxx-ftp
ForceCommand internal-sftp
PasswordAuthentication yes
ChrootDirectory /home/xxx-ftp
PermitTunnel no
AllowAgentForwarding no
AllowTcpForwarding no
X11Forwarding no
```

When I try to ssh, I get the error (at /var/log/auth.log):

> fatal: bad ownership or modes for chroot directory component "/"

I have checked the / permissions:

```
toing@ToingNet:~$ ls -ld /
drwxrwxr-x 26 root root 4096 déc.  16  2021 /
```

And it is owned by root, so why does sftp tell me this?

Comment: Maybe it means the "chroot root"? Ie. `/home/xxx-ftp`?

Comment: This is also root:
`toing@ToingNet:~$ ls -ld /home/xxx-ftp/
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 déc.  21 12:02 /home/xxx-ftp/`

Comment: Should be `xxx-ftp` probably

Comment: tried that, same issue:

Comment: `toing@ToingNet:~$ ls -ld /home/xxx-ftp
drwxr-xr-x 2 xxx-ftp xxx-ftp 4096 déc.  21 12:31`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was that every directory subcomponent should have write access only for root.
In my case, `/` had write permissions for group. but `/home` and `/home/xxx-ftp` permissions were okay.

Once this was resolved everything worked as expected.

**Before**

```
toing@ToingNet:~$ ls -ld /
drwxrwxr-x 28 root root 4096 déc.  21 16:40 /
```

command:

```
sudo chmod g-w /
```

**After**

```
toing@ToingNet:~$ ls -ld /
drwxr-xr-x 28 root root 4096 déc.  21 16:40 /
```

Comment: This `ls -ld /data` command and your notes on root directory ownership helped me narrow down that one of my subdirectories needed chown'd by root:root and needed chmod 755 set, while /data/username needed owned by sftpuser:sftpgroup. Fixed things for me perfectly as I was seeing 'fatal: bad ownership or modes for chroot directory component "/data/sftpuser"' in my /var/log/auth.log logs when sftp'ing in.